# Why would adding a parent with Python make the child unmovable?

Tags: python, parent

update:

As it turns out, it was because I scaled the child object to z = 0 - c.scale(1,1,0) - scaling to non-zero works just fine

---

I have a child called c and a parent called p.

I use Python to create a parent-child relation.

Either:

```
p.select = True
c.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = p
bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type="OBJECT")
p.select = False  
c.select = False
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

or simply:

```
c.parent = p
```

The parent-child relationship is established, which I can confirm in the Outliner.

If I move p in the 3D View the child c will also move, however I cannot move c - it seems locked to it's position, however when I check the locks in the Properties Editor no locks are active. I can alter the location using the transform properties in the Properties Editor, but I can't move it using the mouse. I can scale and rotate as normal though.

Both p (an empty) and c (a text) is created in Python.

If I do the same manually - create the objects and set their parent relationship, I can move the child in the UI. This is the type of relationship I dream of (one where I can move :P ).

How can I add a parent relationship from Python that lets me move both the parent (with the child following) and the child (on its own) from the UI?

Further observations: The problem seems to be in the object creation process. No matter how I parent objects that are Python-created, I end up with not being able to move the child on it's own. I even tried to use the exact same code line that the UI uses to generate the object.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edit. Further information can be added to the question via editing - I think this makes it a bit easier for people reading it.

Comment: That's great - it's actually what I ought to have done - if you wish to, you can delete these comments as well. They have no info-value :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
bpy.ops.object.text_add(location=(0, 0, 0))
a = C.object 
bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES', location=(0, 0, 1))
b = C.object
a.parent = b
a.matrix_parent_inverse = b.matrix_world.inverted()
```

As you can see:

[image]

There must be something wrong with the code you use for creating the objects.
You should try removing the parenting part of your code and see if the code around it works fine.

Comment: Indeed it does - thank you Martin.

The trick seems to be: 

`a.matrix_parent_inverse = b.matrix_world.inverted()`

but I'm not sure what's going on?

Btw. the code around it works as expected

Comment: Seems to work without the line `a.matrix_parent_inverse = b.matrix_world.inverted()` That is only to keep the original transforms of the object that is parented. I am affraid I have no ideas why it might not work without seeing more of your code. I can not find a way to replicate the issue.

Comment: Ok, I'm a newbie with blender :)

The problem was that I scaled the text-object to (1,1,0) - which in real 3D of course is nonsense - I'm going to use it for video, so I don't care about the third D (in this case)

`import bpy`

`C = bpy.context`
`bpy.ops.object.text_add(location=(0, 0, 0))`
`a = C.object `
`a.scale = (1,1,0)`
`bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES', location=(0, 0, 1))`
`b = C.object`
`a.parent = b`

Comment: not very clear - thing is - don't do a.scale(1,1,0)

Comment: Niewbie or not, that is still weird - an object scaled 0 in Z axis should still be movable. I don't think this is supposed to be like that. There might be a bug somewhere there. But then there are quite a few of those in Blender Python's API, it's not perfect. And I don't think it is possible for it to be. Luckily this will most likely not influence the result you are trying to reach.

Comment: yes, it is quite weird. Either blender should accept that an object is scaled to 0 or it should refuse it. Drawing it in the UI but having it function quite different (or not have it functioning at all) makes no apparent sense. 

I was able to rotate and scale, but not move. That makes no apparent sense either. 

I think it's a bug too.

Comment: It's a reported bug, I confirmed.

https://developer.blender.org/T50103

Comment: Well, it is not in any way limmiting you. There is no need for you to scale the text to 0 in Z axis. Fixing it would have no use, it only happens when parenting a text object and scaling it to 0 as far as we are aware. It doesn't happen using the UI as well. It is really not a big deal. I would be surprised if any developer would ever decide to go and fix this. And I don't think anyone should.

Comment: It's not limiting what I can do, that's true, but it's inconsistent and confusing. Anyways, thanks for your help!